# android screen shot app showing black screen in phone but working in emulator

Tags: android, service, screenshot

I have seen some application in android market which are being used to take the screen shot. I want to make an application similar to that.

I found that ASL(Android Screencapture Liberary) should be used to do this task. But When I am running the demo of ASL in emulator it is working fine. But the same app in phone is showing black screen.

I am using Samsung Galaxy Pop S5570(android 2.2.1) for testing purpose.

I need suggestions what could be the possible issue.

I am using the following permissions:

android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

thanks
Manish

Comment: some links which i have tried: http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/downloads/detail?name=asl-1.1.zip&can=2&q= http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android                                                          need help urgently on the above problem.  Please suggest if someone have actually worke on this application.

Comment: some of the sample application are shoot me, screen capture shortcut.

Comment: @llango J: Please seet he code: 'RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.temp_view); Logger.printMessage(TAG, "relative view: "+view,Logger.DEBUG); View v1 = view.getRootView(); v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); v1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); v1.layout(0, 0, v1.getMeasuredWidth(), v1.getMeasuredHeight()); v1.buildDrawingCache(true); Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache()); v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache saveBitmapInGallery(b);'

Comment: please help me find out the solution. I need it urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not supported, for obvious security and privacy reasons. All applications which offer this today either require root or exploit security holes which are being fixed.