# capture screenshot of playing video and mailing that screen shot

Tags: android, video, screenshot

I am playing video, i need to capture video screen shots.
- after i need to mail are share it.

Please provide me examples are any links.

Thanks,
Chandu

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it programmatically, just use eclipse and go to DDMS, and use screen capture, may be this is useful for you : http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-take-screenshots-of-your-android-smartphone
but if you want to do it programmatically, see this : [Screen Capture in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to do programmatically in my application, please provide some examples are links.

Comment: Ok , see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android