# How can I take screen shots from running video in Android

Tags: android, video, screenshot

I have developed an application in android which contains videos. Now I want to take screen shots from that running video. Is anybody having any idea regarding this thing.

Pleas provide some example code or links.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is using MediaPlayer. Put SurfaceView to your layout and provide it to the MediaPlayer. After the playback is begun you will be able to get snapshot from SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the screenshot of your full screen (with status bar and all) you cannot do that programatically unless you have a rooted phone. If you want the screenshot of your app only, then you can.
If you don't want it programatically, then you can-

Go to "Devices" view in eclipse and you have a screenshot (camera like) button there. You can find it from from `Window -> Show View`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. i want do problematically please provide any code are links.

Answer (score 0):

Try android-screenshot-library

these links may help you

1. [capture screenshot of playing video and mailing that screen shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714964/capture-screenshot-of-playing-video-and-mailing-that-screen-shot)
2. http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/w/list

it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Assume your video view is inside a linearlayout, you can try:

```
            linearlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            linearlayout.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm = linearlayout.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Tried and got only a black image. Videos wont display using this method. Works great for images and text.