# Taking a screenshot of a layout in a different resource file

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a layout that's in a different XML file, without showing it. So far I'm able to take a screenshot of the current activity:

From my current activity:

```
public void takeScreenshot(){

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

    Bitmap bitmap = GLOBAL.viewToBitmap(view);

    String filename = "screenshot";
    String folder = "/Pictures";

    Boolean result = GLOBAL.saveBitmap(bitmap, filename, folder);
    String message;

    if(result){
        message = "Screenshot saved in folder " + folder;
    }else{
        message = "Error taking screenshot";
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

From my global class:

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();

    if (bgDrawable != null) {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

public Boolean saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filename, String folder)
{
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + folder);
    myDir.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(myDir, filename + ".png");
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I'm trying to change my takeScreenshot() method, like this:

```
public void takeScreenshot(){
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenshot_layout, null);

    Bitmap bitmap = GLOBAL.viewToBitmap(view);

    String filename = "screenshot";
    String folder = "/Pictures";

    Boolean result = GLOBAL.saveBitmap(bitmap, filename, folder);
    String message;

    if(result){
        message = "Screenshot saved in folder " + folder;
    }else{
        message = "Error taking screenshot";
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

...but the app crashes in the first like of viewToBitmap(), and I get the following while debugging:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

I tried giving the root LinearLayout in my layout file a fixed height and width, and then "wrap_content" with some child elements having fixed dimensions, so the height and width should both be greater than 0. So how can I properly get the view for the layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in code below

```
   View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
   view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   view.getDrawingCache();
```

Please visit [Screen Capture in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android) or [How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) for more help.

give id to your hidden layout and try like this

```
   View view = findViewById(R.id.screenshot_layout).getRootView();
   view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   view.getDrawingCache();
```

try like this now

```
    view.getDrawingCache();
    view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do coding here to save screen shot
    }
   });
```

Comment: But doesn't that take a screenshot from the current activity? I already did that. What I'm trying to do now is capture an image of another layout, one that the user won't see.

Comment: I gave an ID to the parent LinearLayout in my layout file, and did what you suggested, but I still got the same error (that the width and height must be greater than 0).

Comment: I have updated answer. visit here for more help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17745162/5202007

Comment: Still not working. It throws an error at this point:

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.getDrawingCache();

I tried to remove that code, just to check, and the app closed.

Comment: can you update code in your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Basically, I tried what I already posted plus what you have suggested.