# How to use Button onClickListener to trigger screen capture in Android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, screen-capture

How to capture the current scren by using a dedicated button made on the app? I am trying to impliment button onClick listener but getting errors.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, that would include the source code along with the [Java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android help?