# screenshot of Video on surface view shows black screen

Tags: android, surfaceview

```
public void CaptureImages(View v) {
    mSurfaceView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    mSurfaceView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    mSurfaceView.layout(0, 0, mSurfaceView.getMeasuredWidth(), mSurfaceView.getMeasuredHeight());
    mSurfaceView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSurfaceView.getDrawingCache());
    mSurfaceView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MediaApp");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        File fileImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MediaApp"
                + File.separator + "image.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo = null;

        try {

            fileImage.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(fileImage);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        showToast("Error Directory not created");
    }

}
```

This app stream video from internet and displyes it in a surfaceview android.i place a button in the view to take a screenshot of the video.but,it always shows a blackscreen only..Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android

Comment: no.It shows always a black screen...

Comment: fadden. Can you code that and post here.?i want to do it without help of libraries.